# Are there any adverse side effects to calling applicationWillEnterForeground/applicationDidEnterBackground manually on app delegate?

Tags: ios

I have an application that uses geofencing in iOS.  Because of the way geofencing works in iOS, my application is getting launched when not already in memory (`applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`), but the `applicationWillEnterForeground` / `applicationDidEnterBackground` never gets called, because the application is never brought to the foreground to begin with.  This is an issue for my app, as I'm trying to use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) event logging when a region is entered, but Flurry relies on the full foreground to background event cycle to log events.

A workaround I'm considering is to call `applicationWillEnterForeground` / `applicationDidEnterBackground` manually.  Note that I am *not* trying to bring my app into the foreground or close my app programmatically - I just want to "trick" Flurry into thinking the app has been through the full lifecycle so that it logs events.

So, basically what I'm interested in is knowing whether there's likely to be any unintended consequences of calling `applicationWillEnterForeground` / `applicationDidEnterBackground` on my app delegate, or is this a safe enough hack to use for my event logging purposes?

Comment: Do you make explicit calls to Flurry in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` methods of your app delegate?

Comment: No.  I'm kinda treating Flurry as a black box, and I'm not even sure calling these methods on my app delegate will work to trick it.  All I know is that "Flurry depends on the iOS lifecycle to be complete for full reporting" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620675/recording-events-with-flurry-after-app-was-launched-due-to-a-monitored-region-be).

Comment: Since Flurry most likely responds to the appropriate lifecycle notifications, then you making explicit calls to `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` will have no effect on Flurry. You should contact Flurry support about this.

Comment: I'm starting to think the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Well, sort of.

It's certainly not best practice. In fact, Flurry doesn't have access to those methods - I would instead just find the methods Flurry uses to find the life cycle of the app - and call those.

However, if you try this and can't find them, then **go ahead**. However, be careful - test thoroughly!

<sub>I'm sure you've already tested, but does Flurry actually not work in these events?</sub>